# Fill the row in a data frame with a specific value based on a condition on the specific column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame `df`:

```
df=
A   B   C  D
1   4   7  2
2   6  -3  9
-2  7   2  4
```

I am interested in changing the whole row values to `0` if it's element in the column `C` is negative. i.e. if `df['C']<0`, its corresponding row should be filled with the value `0` as shown below:

```
df=
A   B   C  D
1   4   7  2
0   0   0  0
-2  7   2  4
```

Comment: Try this : ``df.loc[df.C.lt(0)] = 0``

Comment: Instead of deleting your question, a better way to acknowledge the answer helped you is by voting on it or marking it accepted. Please don't delete your question again as it is very disrespectful to our time as unpaid volunteers. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403802/ive-rethought-my-question-about-a-homework-assignment-why-cant-i-get-it-delete?cb=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.where` or `mask`:

```
df.where(df['C'] >= 0, 0)

   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  7  2
1  0  0  0  0
2 -2  7  2  4
```

---

Another option is simple masking via multiplication:

```
df.mul(df['C'] >= 0, axis=0)

   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  7  2
1  0  0  0  0
2 -2  7  2  4
```

---

You can also set values directly via `loc` as shown in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352162/fill-the-row-in-a-data-frame-with-a-specific-value-based-on-a-condition-on-the-s#comment115537049_65352162):

```
df.loc[df['C'] <= 0] = 0
df

   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  7  2
1  0  0  0  0
2 -2  7  2  4
```

Which has the added benefit of modifying the original DataFrame (if you'd rather not return a copy).

Comment: How to leave a specific column element and apply it to the remaining elements in a row? For example, I do not want to change the element in A to 0.

Comment: @SaiKiran you can run this code on a subset of the columns and then assign the result back to those columns.